# MKOverlayPathView gets "fuzzy" on high zoom factor

Tags: iphone, objective-c, google-maps, mapkit, overlay

I'm developing an application that uses an [MKOverlayPathView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKOverlayPathView_class/Reference/Reference.html) to highlight certain positions on an MKMapView. Basically the idea is that the overlay path view gets passed a list of CLLocationCoordinate2D structs, then connects them linearly using `CGPathAddLineToPoint()` in its custom `drawRect:` implementation.

However, in both the Simulator and on a device (iPhone 3GS running 4.2.1), I notice some strange behavior: the path behaves perfectly well up to a certain zoom level, then will begin to "fuzz" (for lack of a better term) in certain segments. These problem areas are always sharply delineated, and the rest of the path will be just fine:

[image: fuzzed path]

I've tried calling `setNeedsLayout` and `invalidatePath` on the path view (from the MKMapView's `regionDidChangeAnimated` notification method), but both of those will just cause the fuzzed area to disappear, rather than be redrawn properly. Is there a fix for this?